# yii2 shopping cart ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, shopping-cart

I want to modify existing shopping cart in yii2, so it wouldn't reload the page, means make it work by ajax.
Current cart looks like:

```
 <form method="post" id="form-prodtobuy-<?= $p->id ?>" action="<?= \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["site/cart"]) ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="task" value="update" />
 <input id="<?= $p->id ?>" class="form-control buy-input" name="product[<?= $p->id ?>]" value="<?= Purchase::getCartValue($p->id) ?>" data-id="<?= $p->id ?>" placeholder="0">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buy <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></button>
 </form>
```

It works properly, but reloads the page.

var_dump($_SESSION); after that looks like:

```
 array(2) { ["__flash"]=> array(0) { } ["products"]=> array(3) { [2958]=> string(1) "2" [2959]=> string(1) "1" [2581]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

My obvious solution is to add e.preventDefault() on submit event as follows:

```
 $(document).on('submit', '[id^=form-prodtobuy-]', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var someVar = $('#someInput').val();
     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["site/cart"]) ?>",
        data: {???:someVar},
        .....................
     });
 });
```

What should be in ajax 'data'?
Where or how is it possible to get names of variables to set session properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ajax "data" put form seralization output.

Take care that I've used heredoc format, so last EOT_JS must not have spaces before it.

```
$urlForm = \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["site/cart"]);

$this->registerJs( <<< EOT_JS 

    $(document).on('submit', '[id^=form-prodtobuy-]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "{$url}",
            data: formData,
            function(data) {
                console.log('form submit output');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });

EOT_JS
);
```

Comment: Good point. Tks. But it still reloads the page, even I removed action attr from the form. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: What is the output of form call? Are you sure that output of form call, site/cart, is not a http redirect ?

Comment: No, not sure. Looks like it redirects. Can't find proper file to check. Everything is so messy with yii2. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Check browser console to see what is server response after form call

Comment: And this is exactly the problem, since it shows nothing )

Comment: Sorry, I mean network connection tab, that shows all connections executed by browser. Try to check also "preserve log" to avoid that a full page refresh clean the log.

Comment: It should show redirect in 'initiator' column if any, right? But there is no redirect. From the other hand, what else could cause redirect  when form doesn't contain action attribute at all. So, smth redirects, but it's not clear what exactly.

Comment: @ Fabrizio Caldarelli  Found it. Tks a lot for your help.